# Selecting suggestion in vscode in qoutations adds line breaj rather than selecting that class

Tags: visual-studio-code

See this GIF and you'll see the issue.
it is sooo irritating...
Classes are shown very well by extentions and emmet in vscode
But when I hit enter for selecting the class, it includes a line breaj like in the provided GIF.

[image]

Help only, I know this is just a feature, just tell me how to disable it in VSCODE.